# Comfortable way to keep Debian Buster up to date?

Tags: debian, apt, cron, software-updates, unattended-upgrades

So far I have only used Debian (and other Linux distributions based on Debian) for testing purposes and on non-productive systems. On these systems, I occasionally carried out updates manually via the command line (`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`). Due to the upcoming discontinuation of Windows 7 support and my aversion to Windows 10, I would now like to use Debian Buster on my productively used computer. The choice of a desktop environment is not finished yet, so far I have always preferred XFCE. On this system, I want to make sure that the latest security updates are always installed.
My research led me to realize that there seem to be several options to achieve this (e.g. unattended-upgrades package or cron). At least under Ubuntu there seems to be the possibility to [activate automatic updates comfortably via the desktop](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoWeeklyUpdateHowTo) and to configure their frequency and type of installation. Unfortunately I was not able to reproduce this procedure on a test installation under Debian Buster with XFCE.

Is it possible to use a variant similar to the Ubuntu method on Debian? If not, what would be the gold standard to ensure that Debian is up to date?

Comment: You'll find the necessary steps on the commandline documented at https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades

Comment: @markgraf I know this package but I actually wanted to prevent configuration from the command line.
Am I right in assuming that a comfortable configuration (like on Ubuntu) in Debian is only possible when using Gnome?
I honestly wondered that automatic updates are not active by default.

Comment: As far as I know, you're right.  I guess this is because operations people really want to test updates in their integration environment, before rolling them out on production.  On the other hand:  All you have to do is install the package.  It comes with sane defaults.  And installing packages can be done with a graphical client, too.  And I think there's an option for it somwhere during installation.